# Save 'state' or user entry from a Python Click CLI command

Tags: python, arguments, click, command-line-interface, state

I'd like to save some user entered arguments in a python command in some singleton/memory space and access these arguments later in another command.

Is it possible to do with a python data structure or do I need to write to a text file and read the file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained in the documentations here: https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/complex/
to hold the states/results/inputs:
you can easily write down a class with the required properties/variables and instantiate an object out of it inside any function decorated by "@click.command()" and save the instantiated object inside the default context object of click library using the decorator: @click.pass_context. Then you can easily pass the object to the other commands as a parameter and then manipulate its properties/variable/etc.

here is a sample code:

```
import click

class testRepo(object):
    def __init__(self,experimentID:int):
        self.experimentID:int = experimentID



@click.group
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx,):
    ctx.obj = testRepo(1)



#without passed object
@click.command()
@click.option("-n", "--name", prompt="Insert your name:", help="Gets a first name")
def test1(name):
    click.echo(f'This Is Test1 - name = {name}')


#with passed object
@click.command()
@click.option("-f", "--family", prompt="Insert your family", help="Gets a family name")
@click.pass_obj
def test2(repo_passed_obj,family):
    repo_passed_obj.experimentID = 2
    click.echo(str(repo_passed_obj.experimentID))
    click.echo(f'This Is Test2 - family name is {family}')


cli.add_command(test1)
cli.add_command(test2)

#Call the group commands cli()
cli()
```